# Calling Function From Button Click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, onclick

So, at the bottom of my page I load this js file:

```
 <script src="js/galleryExpand.js"></script>
```

Within that there is a bit of code that goes:

```
// Return on ESC
    $(document).keyup(function(e) {
      if (e.keyCode === 27) {   // ESC key
        if (overlayActive) {
          returnToOriginal();
        }
      }
    });
```

I have a button in the page that I would like to call that function from:

```
<a class="waves-effect waves-light btn btn-large white amber-text btn-flat">I've Read It</a>
```

However, when I try and insert it as an OnClick function:

```
    <a onClick="returnToOriginal();" class="waves-effect waves-light btn btn-large white amber-text btn-flat">I've Read It</a>
```

It says function not recognised.

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong please?

Thanks.

=== EDIT ===
The modal I am trying to close is the same as this one (https://themes.materializecss.com/pages/demo#sacred) I am trying to simulate what the "back" button does in my own button - but I cannot seem to. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You're using jQuery. Why are you putting JS in HTML?

Comment: `returnToOriginal` must be a global function to reach it from other scripts. If the code in your JS file can reach it, but it can't be reached from other scripts, it's probably defined in a local scope.

Comment: Thanks both, basically this plugin populates its own button that closes the "modal". I want to have my own button that closes the modal, but am struggling to get it to close. Copying the class of the other button doesn't work, so I'm just trying to get it to work inline at the moment and then can write a proper onclick handler. Would you be able to recommend what I should do please?

Comment: make sure your `returnToOriginal` function is not inside `$(document).ready(function({ ...})`; your function must have a global scope to be called from `onclick'

Comment: You need to add jQuery library before your `Expand.js` library.

Comment: Can you modify the `galleryExpand.js` script? If so, put that function in  the global scope. You may not be able to actually move it, but you can assign it globally. `window.returnToOriginal = returnToOriginal`.

Comment: Strangely that removes the error but it does not close the modal. The modal I have is the same as on this page (https://themes.materializecss.com/pages/demo#sacred) - I have inserted an extra button into the modal and would like to close it using that - can anyone help please?